# Showing a relation between two specific elements of two different sets, simultaneously as showing their set-membership

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I found myself using the following notation, wondering if it was conventional or clear:

$$X \ni x = g \in G$$

Meaning that $x$, from the set $X$, is equal to $g$, from the set $G$. More generally, I'm asking if the following notation is acceptable:

$X \ni x R g \in G$

Where $R$ is any arbitrary relation applicable to elements (and elements only, due to clarity?).

Is this acceptable notation? I find it elegant and compact. If not, what other alternatives are there. There's of course this alternative:

$$x = g, x \in X \land g \in G$$

It is only slightly less compact, to the point where I don't care, but it does use more symbols and more repeats of symbols. Thus, I find it less elegant. What I find elegant or not though, is irrelevant if my notation is unclear or too unconventional. So, is it?

Comment: Not very clear... Is it so necessary to "save" a pair of blank spaces? $x \in X, g∈G \text { and } x=g$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It isn't so necessary, it just looks nice in my eyes. But, I haven't seen it before, so I got doubtful if it was conventional and clear. Why did you find it unclear?

Comment: IMO, too "compact" an expression may decrease readibility: we are humans...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hmm, interesting. Are you able to elaborate on how the compactness itself causes lower readability? Or is there some other property that usually (or always) accompanies the compactness that causes the lower readability?

Comment: Simple example with logic and [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation). Often on this site you can find questions asking about the "need" for parentheses, both in arithmetic and logic. The answer is NO: we have rules/conventions about the "priority" of operations and thus we have only to apply them.

Comment: Now consider this simple formula, where I've used paretheses for readibility: $(\lnot p \lor q) \land r$ and the same written using prefix notation (totally "equivalent" and for sure the preferred one for a machine): $\land r\lor \lnot p q$. The second one is "more compact" for sure: do you honestly can prefer it?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't prefer it, but that's due to a lack of familiarity. Also, as for the rules regarding the priority of operations; I still prefer parentheses because then I don't have to remember all of those things. In that case, it isn't the compactness that is the problem, just the need for knowledge that I don't usually have (I might learn it at some point but I usually forget because I don't need to use it most of the time). I mean $4 + 3 \times 2$ is better than $4 + (3 \times 2)$, because the first is more compact and contains no redundancies. Here, we know, so there's no issue.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The only inference from your examples about why you think compactness can (in)directly cause lower readability, is that compactness usually comes with more need for knowledge (like priority of operations), or the more compact notation is usually more obscure, like in the case of the Polish notation. Was this your message behind the examples?